# Can I use Kamailio Sip Server to handle 500 calling?

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip

I need a Sip server to build a VIOP server to establish voice call between 500 Android an desktop sip clients.
Can Kamailio handle this or I need an Asterisk server too?

Comment: http://www.kamailio.org/w/features/

Comment: Thanks, I searched a lot but I'm not sure if it's possible. Do you familiar with kamailio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamailio is only an SIP proxy (call negotiation), you still need a RTP server in order to handle the audio of the calls like Asterisk or FreeSwitch